# Unison fails to synchronize some git repositories

Tags: unison

I use Unison 2.40.65 on Kubuntu 13.04, both computer use ecryptfs to encrypt the home folder.

I try to sync my complete home folder to my netbook, I get errors that the temp file disappeared, see screenshots of the errors here:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

I can copy those file using a plain `rsync -avhE --delete`, but it does not work with Unison.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eCryptFS unfortunately has a 143 character filename limit: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/344878

unison 2.40.65 does not know about this specific limit, and sometimes creates temporary files that go over it. Such files can not be created on eCryptFS mounts.

There is a patch for unison so that it creates filenames that stay within even the eCryptFS limit: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.network.unison.devel/2258 -- interestingly, the mailing list post announcing the patch also cites your superuser question. :)